# per-container optimizations for functions that operate on iterators

Tags: c++

So I know the point of iterators is to abstract the underlying container so you don't have to worry about what it is. 
But say you wanted to write an optimized version of merge sort and wanted to do an in place sort if the underlying container was a linked list, since you can run merge sort in-place on a linked list without the need for extra container allocations.

Is there any way to get this information to know whether you're operating on a linked structure and/or access the pointers for Standard Library and other containers?

I'm assuming there is a way since that is what `std::sort does`? How?

Comment: Somebody down-voted the question without commenting...
What exactly is wrong with this question?

Comment: I did not downvote, but the question is stating something incorrect, that is not what `std::sort` does.

Comment: As a user, you can't, but the implementation can. For instance, if l is a list, gcc-5 can compute `std::distance(l.first(),l.end())` in constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also always wished for a way to do this, but the answer is kind-of, but not really. This isn't possible in general, because of the template deduction rules.
Each iterator may be a member of a class, but since multiple classes may have the same iterators, if a function receives these iterators, it is literally and theoretically impossible to deduce which container it came from.  That hinders things somewhat.

If you don't need the container type and can work with the iterator type alone, then yes, `std::sort` could optimize based on the underlying container.  But no, `std::sort` doesn't have a special algorithm for node based containers in any C++ standard library that I know of.

The containers themselves sometimes have specialized versions, see `std::list<T>::sort`, but the generic `std::sort` can't make use of that since it works on any arbitrary range, and `std::list<T>::sort` only works on the entire container.

---

I really wish they would.  Also a specialization of `std::lower_bound` and similar when called on the tree-based containers would be awesome.

Comment: So the convention is to put specialized sorting functions within the containers. Big revelation for me, I have always just stuck to `std::sort` and assumed it was optimizing for container types.
More interestingly, however, `C++17` is providing some new iterator functionality including a `Contiguous Iterator` and [container access functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) (see at the bottom). Given these new constructs, do you think this would be enough to make this scenario possible?

Comment: Containers may still have specialized sorts defined within, but at the very least do you think general use functions such as `std::sort` would be able to discover and/or call these functions?

Comment: Is it not possible that the sort function can optimize the algorithm based on the type of iterator's received?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: Unlikely, because `std::sort` works on any arbitrary subset, whereas the optimized versions only work on the whole container, and `sort` can't know about the containers, only the iterators.  The last paragraph in this post answer that: theoretically yes, but no `std::sort` does to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A library implementor can do a certain set of things that are not portable and depend on the details of the implementation. While in the standard the iterator types are referred as nested types in the container, nested types are not deducible, the implementation can decide to implement those as types with namespace scope, which are deducible, and provide a nested typedef. The implementation could then, within the limits of the requirements placed in the standard, optimize the operations.

I don't know of any implementation that implements `std::sort` as merge sort for lists, but there are other tricks that are used in implementations, for example `std::copy` when the iterators are into vectors holding POD types is implemented in some libraries by calling `std::memmove` rather than copying one element at a time.

As I mentioned before, while this can be done by the implementor, writing your own code attempting to do the same would be non-portable and brittle, as it would depend on details of one implementation that might change in the next version of the library or even by changing compiler flags.

Comment: std::sort is only defined for random access iterators, it isn't defined for list iterators, so that not-existing implementation is not specialized to take advantage of nodes.